# Flag post options

Tags: bug

I flagged my first post today. The options on the pop up only showed need moderator attention, but in the help section it shows a few more options. Do the other options only come with more privilege or is it a bug?

Comment: If you are flagging a very old question, a smaller than usual popup can appear with just two options.  The popup will contain the words "*Too old to migrate*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The privilege to raise flags is available when you have reached 15 reputation.

For clarity this is the pop-up you should see when you click to raise a flag on a question:

[image]

I'm not sure why only the in need of moderator intervention option would pop up, it might be useful to include a screenshot of what you are experiencing.

As far as I am aware once you have the ability to raise a flag all of the options should be available to you. I suggest trying the flag button on a couple of different posts, just to be certain that you are experiencing a bug. And that it wasn't just some one time glitch in the system.

Comment: Thanks I will try to remember to get a screen shot next time.  I have the ability to flag so I will test it out and see what happens. I only know how to take screen shots using scrot in the terminal, is there another option that you know of?

Comment: For most operating systems the print screen button on your keyboard should work. For Windows there is the snipping tool which allows you to "snip" part of the screen and save it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your account has no prohibitions against flagging of any kind, and the only reputation barrier to flagging is a binary one at 15 reputation.

My thought is that maybe you flagged a comment, which does get a significantly smaller box. If you flag a question, you get a large modal that looks like this:

[image: flag a question modal].

Whereas if you flag a comment it looks like this:

[image: flag a comment modal].

Do either of these look like what you saw? If you saw the second modal on question and can reproduce the issue, I'm sure SO would be interested in a bug report.

Comment: Yes actually the first box but only the one option , In need of moderator attention. I have not had to flag again but I think I may have flagged a question as an answer.  I am not sure what to do now..

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question because I have figured it out It  is an err on my part. I flagged my own answer to a question I was trying to flag.  I thought I left a comment for the user that posted not an answer and tried to flag the question for the moderator. I failed.
I guess this is a learning experience..without posting and getting answers and comments from everyone, I would not realize all that  I had done wrong. Including asking the question and not showing my work I went back and tried it it is the problem. I tried to take a screen shot but I am having trouble. I will however figure it out and post a screen shot later. Thank you all for helping and for ypur patience with a new guy. I appreciate the time you all take to help.
P.S. I am learning more and more everyday as you can probably tell I am self taught and proud of myself.

Comment: Pismurf, this gave me a good laugh at the end of a long day. I was able to reproduce your issue. Thank you for reporting back!

Comment: LOL good to be the comic pl relief.  When I realized that others had invested time into a operator error rather than a potential bug I almost deleted my account with a vow never to return